# Can I use direct load even if I have SQL functions in the control file?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have 100 million records to load to a table. I am sqlldr to do so. I have been using the conventional load but is taking long. In the control file I have SQL functions to substring and other data manipulations. My question is, can I use direct load even if I have SQL functions in the control file?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: 11g. I do not have privileges to run the required script to prepare the database for direct load so I cannot test myself. I am doing research first so that I can propose this idea

Answer (score 0):

That should be no problem.  Per Oracle [12.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-993D209A-23CC-466D-B8C7-D508C17C921A.htm#SUTIL1293) Direct Load cannot be used for:

- Clustered tables
- Virtual Private Database policies active on INSERT
- Segments with active trasactions pending
- BFILE columns
- Create Sequence statements

For [Oracle 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_modes.htm#SUTIL1294), an additional restriction is you cannot load a parent table together with a child table.

Comment: For your last statement, is that for example an index?